# How to discern this clause, grammatically? Word arrangement?

Tags: clauses, syntax

> “**Then came upon a world in ruins an anxious youth**. The children were drops of burning blood which had inundated the earth; they were born in the bosom of war, for war. **For** fifteen years they had dreamed of the snows of Moscow and of the sun of the Pyramids. ” 
>   ― Alfred de Musset, *The Confession of a Child of the Century*

*anxious youth*, subject, and noun phrase? Why may it get placed after everything? I may not get what sentence, grammatically, one may report this? May it seem like passive? I may think in passive, it may go object verb subject. Here it seems to go *came* verb, *a world in ruins* noun phrase(object[?]), *an anxious youth* noun phrase, subject?

And may *For* in this get utilized like a conjunction?

Comment: The 'repackaging' in the first sentence is a literary device for rhetorical effect. It reflects the emotional language of the original (this is not an English work but an early 20th-century translation of a high-Romantic 1836 French novel). ... *For* is an ordinary preposition with a temporal sense -- "How long had they dreamed?" "They had dreamed for fifteen years."

Comment: I think I thought it maybe seemed like a preposition, or prepositional phrase. Why may it not get a comma after I think they may frequently go like, like *For fifteen years, they had dreamed of the snows of Moscow and of the sun of the Pyramids.*

Comment: A comma is unnecessary with such a short phrase: it is obvious when the phrase ends.

Comment: So a comma may maybe not seem perpetually requested there. All right. I thank you, StoneyB.

Answer (score 1):

This is inversion, yes. Stiff and unnatural.

> Then came upon a world in ruins an anxious youth

An anxious youth then came upon a world in ruins.

An anxious youth then encountered a world which was in a state of ruin.

When every edifice --all buildings, all bridges -- is crumbling, the world is "in ruins".   In a state of ruination.

> For fifteen years they had dreamed of the snows of Moscow and of the
>   sun of the Pyramids.

All during the last fifteen years, they had dreamed of the snows of Moscow and (had dreamed) of the sun of the Pyramids.

Comment: So I guess it may seem like a passive clause and a verb may get permitted to go there and not go maybe like object, verb, subject, and seem maybe grammatically all right?

Comment: @saySay You could also do it this way: "Then came an anxious youth upon a world in ruins" -- which is also 'literary'.

Comment: I guess I maybe don’t not like how this writer wrote this. (May that not seem too not all right.) I guess I aimed to discern if it, a verb going there and how it got written, seemed all right grammatically. (I may not get literary.) (I don’t think I customarily observe sentences placed like this.) And It seems *Then came upon a world in ruins an anxious youth* does seem grammatically all right. So I guess a verb may go in a not passive sentence former to placing a subject? That seems interesting. I thank you.

Comment: @saySay: It's an *extremely* stiff and unnatural inversion in your specific example, but that's largely because the verb *came* is further modified by *upon a world in ruins* before we even get to the displaced subject (*an anxious youth*, itself an unusual and potentially ambiguous noun phrase). But *The English Lionesses actually outplayed Japan during the second half. Then came the disastrous own goal* is more "reasonable". There's no "passive" aspect to any versions given so far (that would be *A world in ruins was come upon by an anxious youth*, which is an even less likely utterance).